# How do I display content in a Rails view and exclude a couple of pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to Rails and I need to display a link to javascript file in a view but I need to exclude a couple of pages. This thing is written in haml. I need something like:

```
-if request.url != 'My Link' || request.url != 'My Other Link'
  =javascript_include_tag 'My javascript file'
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little clumsy right now because of a [bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9360) in `content_for`. Until that bug is fixed, I think the best approach would be to have your layout file include the javascript only if special content wasn't provided by an individual view:

```
- if content_for(:exclude_javascript) != "exclude" then
   = javascript_include_tag 'My javascript file'
```

Then in the few views where you don't want the javascript, provide the special content:

```
- content_for :custom_javascript, "exclude"
```

---

Once the fix for `content_for` is available, the approach will be cleaner. You'll be able to have your layout contain:

```
=  content_for(:custom_javascript) || javascript_include_tag 'My javascript file'
```

and your special views contain:

```
content_for :custom_javascript, ""
```